# XSLT <xsl:key> fails when indexing 2 identical nodesets

Tags: xslt, key

Hello for my first question on stackoverflow :-)

I've experienced a strange behaviour with the xsl:key function in XSLT, wich is a bit hard to explain, but easy to demonstrate.

When I'm indexing 2 different but exactly identical nodesets with the xsl:key element, it fails to index them properly.

In this test example I want to know how many cells have been indexed for each table. Here is my first input with 2 exactly identical tables (exept for the @id):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<test>
    <table id="table1">
        <cell>Cell 1</cell>
        <cell>Cell 2</cell>
        <cell>Cell 3</cell>
    </table>
    <table id="table2">
        <cell>Cell 1</cell>
        <cell>Cell 2</cell>
        <cell>Cell 3</cell>
    </table>
</test>
```

Then my second input with a slightly different content for the second table (first cell contains "cell_1" with an underscore):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<test>
    <table id="table1">
        <cell>Cell 1</cell>
        <cell>Cell 2</cell>
        <cell>Cell 3</cell>
    </table>
    <table id="table2">
        <cell>Cell_1</cell>
        <cell>Cell 2</cell>
        <cell>Cell 3</cell>
    </table>
</test>
```

Here is my XSLT. I'm counting for each table element, the number of cells sharing the same current parent::table.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
version="1.0">

    <xsl:key name="cell" match="//cell" use="parent::table"/>

    <xsl:template match="//test">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="table">
        <numcells id_table="{@id}">
            <xsl:value-of select="count(key('cell', .))"/>
        </numcells>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

And here is the first output with the 2 identical tables. It shows 6 cells in each table instead of 3.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<test>
    <numcells id_table="table1">6</numcells>
    <numcells id_table="table2">6</numcells>
</test>
```

And now the second output with 2 different tables. It shows the right number of 3 cells for each table.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<test>
    <numcells id_table="table1">3</numcells>
    <numcells id_table="table2">3</numcells>
</test>
```

It may be related to the XSLT processor, but I've tested it with Saxon, Xalan and XSLTProc with the same result.

I've seen that I could get around the problem by using the @id:

```
<xsl:key name="cell" match="//cell" use="parent::table/@id"/>
```

And then:

```
<xsl:value-of select="count(key('cell', @id))"/>
```

But I'm still wondering what is causing this behaviour. Thanks for your explanations!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A key value is a primitive value like a string or a number, not the node itself. If you want to key on node identity then use `use="generate-id(parent::table)"`.

Your current key is the string value of the `table` element and that is the concatenation of all text descendant nodes so for the first sample you get key values like

```
Cell 1
Cell 2
Cell 3
```

You want to group or key based on the identity of a node, not based on its string contents. So use `generate-id` or use the `id` attribute that is present on your `table` elements, as you have already found out.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it makes sense. I see now that it's even written in the XSLT specs. Your generate-id() solution is better than mine using juste the id, because it doesn't rely on the input.